# solving equation with exponents on desired variable

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I have this equation given $1=\alpha^{(CW-1)} N$ and it solution has been given as $\alpha=N^{ \frac{-1}{CW-1}} $.
I want to obtain same expression for $\alpha$ but i am unable to get it. I tried to solve it by taking natural log (ln) on both sides and i get something like this 
$\alpha=\frac{-N}{CW-1}$.

Can any body tell what mistake i have made and what steps i should do to get the correct solution.

Comment: If $a^n = b$, then $a=b^{1/n}$, $n \ne 0$

Comment: Perhaps you should have gotten $\ln \alpha = \frac{-\ln N}{CW-1}$?

Comment: Is you queston : through which steps do we get the solution that is given?

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

$\begin{align*}
  N
    &= \alpha^{-(C W - 1)} \\
  N^{-\frac{1}{C W - 1}}
    &= \alpha
\end{align*}$

Comment: Thanks what if i had $4=\alpha^{(CW-1)} N$